# How is range calculated by a GPS receiver?

Tags: gps, satellite

I wanted some help on understanding how range is calculated by a GNSS/GPS receiver(rx), I tried looking on google, but can't find the required results.

C/A codes repeat every 1 ms and the rx delays internally generated sequence untill it correlates with the sequence it receives from the satellite. Thus the `delay' can only be between 0 to 1 milli second, which means the distance between satellites and rx can be [0, 300) km. Where as the actual distance is around 20,000 km.

What am i missing?

Comment: 1. That the 1ms is the ambiguity for C/A code, not the 50Hz nav message modulated on top. 2. That you have more than one pseudo-range measurement (at least 4).